# Getting started with GRETA Regular Expression Library

Tags: cl.exe, greta

I'm required to work on GRETA Regular Expression Library, provided by Microsoft Research. I was unable to compile and run the sample program when used `cl.exe` provided with Visual Studio 2008. It gave some errors like:

```
D:\greta\greta-2.6.4>cl /EHsc num_match.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    num_match.cpp
    d:\greta\greta-2.6.4\restack.h(355) : warning C4346: 'regex::hetero_stack<Alignm
    entT,RuntimeTypeCheckT,AssumePodT,DynamicBlockSizeT,StaticBlockSizeT>::stack_nod
    e::header' : dependent name is not a type
            prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
            d:\greta\greta-2.6.4\restack.h(854) : see reference to class template in
    stantiation 'regex::hetero_stack<AlignmentT,RuntimeTypeCheckT,AssumePodT,Dynamic
    BlockSizeT,StaticBlockSizeT>' being compiled
    d:\greta\greta-2.6.4\restack.h(355) : error C2923: 'regex::hetero_stack<Alignmen
    tT,RuntimeTypeCheckT,AssumePodT,DynamicBlockSizeT,StaticBlockSizeT>::aligned_siz
    eof' : 'regex::hetero_stack<AlignmentT,RuntimeTypeCheckT,AssumePodT,DynamicBlock
    SizeT,StaticBlockSizeT>::stack_node::header'
```

It is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'.

Can anybody help me to get started with GRETA?

Comment: Where did you get the num_match.cpp sample program from? Google isn't showing anything for it so maybe you should include the sample code.

Comment: did you check the documentation for greta library on msdn? it has the code.

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/projects/greta/ and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/greta_sample.aspx?display=Print